# Error when importing CSV via MAGMI

Tags: mysql, magento, csv, magmi

When I try to import large number of products with csv file (via *MAGMI*) to Magento, I get this error:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'sort_order' cannot be null - ERROR ON RECORD #1

There is no column or data name like 'Sort Order' on my csv file

What's causing this error? How can I solve it?

Comment: do you have a column named sort_order in your MySQL database?

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky Not sure, which table should I check the 'sort_order'?

Comment: Difficult for me to answer, as I don't know your database structure. You might know where the data from the CSV goes?

Comment: @SaagarEliasJacky I see I think this is great hint to solve I will def check Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Check the table or tables into which data from the CSV is being imported to. There should be a column named `sort_order`, which is setup such that it won't accept a `null` value.

Map that database table column to a column in the CSV and make sure that the column in CSV is not missing values. You need to have some value in that column in the CSV as your `sort_order` column in the MySQL database will not accept a `null` value.